# How to create a single view node in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There doesn't seem to be a way to create React Native View nodes independently like following:

```js
var Label = new Label();
```

Everything in React Native seems to be queued up in UIManager.
My question is: is there a way to do the above with React Native?

Something like the following:

```js
const viewNode = new UiManager.View();
```

instead of:

```js
export function Something() {
  return <View/> // here is just a virtual dom node, not real native view instance
}
```

Comment: I don't think you will get the native view instance directly within the JavaScript part of react-native without any further work. Just out of curiosity, why would you need the native instance?

Comment: I want to leverage React Native and provide integration with higher level templating frameworks. It's a common conception that working directly with native instances is the most efficient way.